# Dockerize rails app with postgres - connection to postgres issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a rails app with postgres and I am having issues running the app in Docker. I have followed around 20 online tutorials and YouTube vides where they cover how to dockerize a rails app and I do exactly as them and it works for them but it does not work for me. I get an error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'bikeramp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Whatever I do, it just does not work. I've already tried everything and I don't understand why it works for them and it does not work for me.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.4-alpine
RUN echo "@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add build-base && apk --no-cache add \
  tzdata \
  bash \
  git \
  libstdc++ \
  ca-certificates \
  libffi-dev \
  postgresql-dev \
  postgresql-client \
  linux-headers \
  libpq \
  openssh \
  file \
  libxml2-dev \
  curl \
  nodejs \
  gmp-dev \
  musl \
  shared-mime-info \
  && echo ‘gem: --no-document’ > /etc/gemrc

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

RUN gem install bundler:2.2.24
RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
RUN bundle install

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

This is my config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: postgres
  password: password
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: bikeramp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: bikeramp_test
```

I am on Mac, docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396.
Appreciate your help.

UPDATE:
I even put this command after COPY . /app

```
RUN mv config/database.yml.docker config/database.yml
```

but the file does not get renamed.

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: @Moussa I've now updated the error message. The rest is just a rails stacktrace, not very meaningful so I didn't add it here.